# Bottleneck in the Eigen partial_lu_inplace when factorizing a large number of small matrices

Tags: eigen

I need to factorize ~1e05 small matrices of maximal *variable* size of 20x20. Profiling of the matrix factorization using HpcToolkit shows that the hotspot in the code is in `Eigen::internal::partial_lu_inplace`.

I checked the [Eigen documenation on the inplace matrix decomposition](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__InplaceDecomposition.html), and I understand it can be important for large matrices to use inplace decomposition, to re-use the memory and have better cache efficiency.

I am currently computing the decomposition like this:

```
// Factorize the matrix.
matrixFactorization_ = A_.partialPivLu();
```

Profiling with [HpcToolkit](http://hpctoolkit.org/) shows that the inplace factorization is the hotspot:

[image]

Is it possible to disable the inplace decomposition and test if the code will be faster for small matrices I am dealing with?

Note: If you look at the CPU time in the column on the image, you'll notice the runtime is in seconds: I am not after microsecond optimizations here, the calculation takes ~4 seconds in total.

**Edit**: HPCToolkit statistically profiles the code **in fully optimized mode** `-O3` , but with the information that is required to map the measurements to the sourcecode `-g3`.

Answer (score 4):

If the profiler gives you so detailed information then you forgot to enable compiler's optimizations (e.g., -O3 -march=native -DNDEBUG, or "Release" mode + /arch:AVX with VS). With Eigen, this will make a huge difference.

Then you might save dynamic memory allocation by using:

```
typedef Matrix<double,Dynamic,Dynamic,ColMajor,20,20> MatMax20;
MatMax20 A_;
PartialPivLU<MatMax20> matrixFactorization_;
```

The matrix `A_` and all internals of `PartialPivLU` will thus be statically allocated.

To update an existing facto better write:

```
matrixFactorization_.compute(A_);
```

Comment: Nope, I have compiled in the fully optimized mode, see the HPCToolkit documentation. The code is optimized, but with debug information that allows mapping the statistical measurements to the source code.

Comment: Also, I have a variable sized matrices, so I cannot fix the size at compile time, the max size 20x20 was just to give a hint of the system size. Is there a simple way to disable the inplace operations in Eigen?

Comment: The typedef suggested by ggael does give you dynamic sized-matrices which are limited to 20x20. This avoids dynamic allocations when creating matrices and the LU-decomposition.

Comment: @tmaric: "disable the inplace operations" -> this does not make sense, the `partial_lu_inplace` function you see is what computes the LU factorization internally. This has little to do with the documentation you referenced. So beyond the optimization I suggested, there is not much you can do, except computing multiple factorizations in parallel using, e.g., openmp on your side.

Comment: @chtz: the unit tests seem to be running faster with pre-initialized max matrix sizes. Enabling vectorization with `-march=native` does not bring much for the smaller unit tests, I will run the larger tests with this option and see if it helps. @ggael: OK, understood, thanks for the help! @ggael: if you remove the part of your answer regarding the debugging and optimization flags, I can accept it. Fixing max matrix size helped make the tests run faster.